# .NET Web API with Knockout JSON deserialization returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I am trying to pass a model representing an Attorney from a Knockout front end to a Web API back end action through a jquery ajax POST, but the parameter the controller action receives is null.

For purposes of customizing what data gets passed, we are using a server-side viewmodel AttorneyViewModel, whose constructor builds its fields from a passed in Attorney from our Entity Framework. My controller action looks like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateAttorney(string id, [FromBody] AttorneyViewModel updatedAttorney)
    {
        var attorney = EntityRepository.AttorneyById(Guid.Parse(id));
        if (attorney == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Attorney not found");
        }

        ...
        // Set values of Attorney entity based on viewmodel
        ...


        try
        {
            EntityRepository.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString());
        return msg; 
    }
```

My server side viewmodel looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class AttorneyViewModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AttorneyId")]
    public string AttorneyId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "BarNumber")]
    ...
    // More values
    ...

    // Constructor
}
```

My knockout observables match these Data Members. When I load the page, a GetAllAttorneys method sends a C# AttorneyViewModel to Knockout and it serializes just fine. But on a POST (create or update), the AttorneyViewModel parameter is null. If I modify my method to use the EF Attorney model, it deserializes just fine. I just don't want to use the EF model because it causes other problems that aren't related to this post.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my setup or is this a known problem?

**EDIT**

My KO view model is hard to show because we've abstracted a lot of the functionality to other view models, but it has these attributes, along with some functions and other front-end-only attributes:

```
this.attorneyId = ko.observable('');
this.name = ko.observable('');
this.barNumber = ko.observable('');
this.practitionerType = ko.observable('');
this.firmName = ko.observable('');
this.email = ko.observable('');
this.phone = ko.observable('');
this.address = ko.observable(new jmp.ko.vm.Address({}));
```

The address is another view model. My function for updating -- abstracted to a view model called Entity -- looks like this:

```
update: function (returnFunction) {
    if (this.urls.update) {
        var self = this;
        var url = this.urls.update + self.id();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: self.toSimple('pascal'),
            success: returnFunction
        });
    } else {
        console.error("viewModel Entity.update(): this.urls.update does not exist.");
    }
}
```

As you can see from the ajax call, I convert the attributes between camel and pascal casing when communicating between front and back end. This was done before I found out about DataContract, but it shouldn't matter because my datamember names are in pascal casing.

Comment: Show your front end code for posting and your KO view model.

Comment: I added what I think you were asking for. Let me know if you need to see anything else. I make use of some helper functions I wrote but for which I haven't inculded the code in the interest of brevity and relevance, such as `toSimple`.

Comment: Are you sending JSON data to your server?  Usually you indicate this by setting the `dataType` parameter to `json` in the jQuery ajax call, but I don't see that in your code.

Comment: I am. The `toSimple` method basically works by using `ko.toJSON` to get the JSON string of the view model, modifies the string, then uses `jquery.parseJSON`. I could specify the dataType parameter for readability, but I don't think it's the source of the problem given that simply changing the parameter type in the controller action to 'Attorney' causes the deserialization to work correctly.

Comment: @JohnK: That actually is (probably) the source of your problem. Or at least part of it. If you are sending JSON, you need to set `dataType`. But I don't quite understand why you are using `ko.toJSON`, then modifying it (which is almost certainly NOT what you want to do) and  then `parseJSON` to convert it back to an object. You really need to add `toSimple` to your question.

Comment: Have you used the Service Trace Viewer Tool ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx

It'll allow you to see what's being sent and received, where it's failing.